What is the difference between and Indefinite Adjectives and Indefinite Pronouns?
What is the difference between Indefinite Adjectives and Indefinite Pronouns?
Is there a different? Is there usage the only difference? Do they not decline the same? Do I translate them differently?

Indefinite Adjective aliqui, aliqua, aliquod
Indefinite Pronoun aliquis, aliquid

They are one and the same. The only formal difference (as you already know) is in the nominative singular.
“Do I translate them differently?” – you probably should, because adjectives and pronouns may work differently in the language you are translating to. If you are translating into English, then obviously you tend to translate aliqui as “some” or “any” and aliquis as “someone, anyone, something,” etc. For example, si te dolor aliqui corporis tenuit must be translated as “If some bodily pain prevented you” (from going to the games, Cic. Ad. fam. 7, 1). You cannot very well say “if someone pain prevented you.”
Bonus fact – psst, don't tell anyone, but even the ancient Romans sometimes used aliquis adjectively and aliqui pronominally. It's rather rare and is in some cases done for reasons of euphony, but even Cicero was caught writing: num igitur aliquis dolor aut omnino post mortem sensus in corpore est? (Tusc. 1, 82; is there any pain or any sensation at all in the body after death?)
We non-Ciceros should probably not make that a habit, though.
